# Creating production-like container for CI/CD with Firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, docker, continuous-integration, firebase-hosting

I am trying to implement a **CI/CD workflow with *Firebase hosting*** as production environment. So, I am writing a Dockerfile that reproduce Firebase environment.

The problem is: I don't find any technical documentation about **how is made  Firebase hosting environment**.

What should I put into my Dockerfile ? Could a simple HTTP server be sufficient ?

Comment: Firebase products are fully cloud hosted, and there are no provisions to run your own instances of any of those products.  There are just some local emulators for development and testing.

Comment: I am talking about dev and test environments that run respectively locally and on a GitLab on premise server

Comment: And `firebase serve --only hosting` isn't going to work for you?

Comment: My concern is not about just making the app work, but about getting the exact same container for each environment (CI/CD purpose). So even if ng serve works, I don't want my container to be ubuntu:latest if thé Firebase env is debian:latest (for example)

Comment: I don't see that it matters at all for the Firebase Hosting emulator, which is only an approximation of what is actually provided in the cloud by Fastly.  You might be trying to solve a problem that just doens't exist.

Comment: I am not solving a problem, I am just respecting the CI/CD workflow that assume the different environment are exactly the same. This is the only way you can ensure there will be no problem when deploying to production. By using Firebase emulator, you can make the app work. But if you have a bug when installing firebase-tools dependencies, for example, it will not be the same fix in dev/test and prod and the CI/CD workflow comes to be dangerous for the app lifecycle.

Comment: I'd just pick one and run with it. The emulator runs equally well on Windows, Macos, and a variety of Linuxes.  Firebase Hosting in production doesn't advertise an OS runtime, because all it does is serve static content, honoring your configuration.  You don't deploy code to run on it.  You don't depend on a version of node.  You just configure and deploy.

Comment: So you are saying that even if I have a different OS, it can not, in any case, imply bugs in dev/test side that do not appear in prod and vice/versa ?
So, the only dependencies would be Node.js and firebase-tools in dev and test ?

Comment: As I said before, the emulator is just an approximation of the actual product.  It's there so you can develop locally without having to go through the trouble of doing an actual deployment and incurring actual costs.  You can't infer any other relationship between the emulator and the actual product.  If you observe a problem with either one, all you can really do is file a bug report.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my conclusion is that it's **not possible** to create Firebase hosting production-like container. As stated in the comments, all environments should use `angular-cli` emulator in order to simulate production environment.